# Run time error: type mismatch, how do I fix this?

Tags: vba, ms-access

> 

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
    
    
    Me!Clear.Visible = False
    Me!SearchPurchaseOrderNumber = Null
    Me!SearchLotNumber = Null

    Dim serialnumber As Variant
       serialnumber = Right(DMax("LotNumber", "R01ReceivingFormToday"), 2)

    If DCount("LotNumber", "R01ReceivingFormToday") = 0 Then
        
       Me!LotNumber = Me!Today & "-01"
    
        Else
 
           ** Me!LotNumber = Format(Me!Today, "000000") & "-" & Format(serialnumber + 1, "00")**

    End If

End Sub
```

I'm getting this Run-time error '13': Type mismatch. when I debug it points to the bolded line. Not sure how to go about this, as it was working perfectly fine for a year until yesterday?

I tried to make sure that in the References dialog box, reference of DAO object library has greater priority, because I read that that is a common issue.. Still no solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

Although you declared serialnumber as a Variant, it will be a String value when you evaluate:

```
Format(serialnumber + 1, "00")
```

Try:

```
Format(Val(serialnumber) + 1, "00")
```